# datatables hiding column on it's own

Tags: jquery, datatables

What might be causing my column to be hidden / compressed. A plus sign is put next to the row. Sorry i'm not sure what this is called to check the datatables site.

[image]

It happens after calling column adjust to fix the headers once the modal is shown.

```
    var dtUsers = $('#table-user-results').DataTable({
        scrollY: "40vH",
        scroller: true,
        responsive: true
    });

    $(document).on('shown.bs.modal', '#list-manage-users-modal', function () {
        dtUsers.columns.adjust().draw();
    });
```

The table

```
<table id="table-user-results" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hovered dataTable">
                <thead class="">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th>Role</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach (var user in Model)
                    {
                        <tr id="@user.ID" class="@(!user.Email.Equals(User.Identity.Name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) ? "user-results-context" : "")">
                            <td>@user.LastName, @user.FristName</td>
                            <td>@user.Email</td>
                            <td>@user.RoleName</td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

***ISSUE UPDATE***

So the problem is triggered when there is not enough data that requires scroller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using [Responsive](https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/) extension which hides columns when they don't fit the view.

However if you're displaying the table in the modal window, Responsive extension may improperly detect column widths because the table was initially hidden.

The solution to that is to use [`responsive.recalc()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/responsive.recalc()) API method in addition to `columns.adjust()`.

Since you're using Scroller extension, you also need to call [`scroller.measure()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/scroller.measure%28%29) API method.

See the the code below:

```
$(document).on('shown.bs.modal', '#list-manage-users-modal', function (){
    $($.fn.dataTable.tables(true)).DataTable()
       .columns.adjust()
       .responsive.recalc()
       .scroller.measure();
});
```

Also you need to include `scrollCollapse: true` option as there seems to be a incompatibility bug in these two extensions. See [issue #854 on GitHub](https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/issues/854) for more details.

See [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/2oL768Ln/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: HA ... thanks, odd thing is it fits just fine when I remove it.

Comment: @Tsukasa, it's a great extension, I would not remove it. I added explanation as to why it hides the column and the workaround.

Comment: To get this to work properly, I had to add true here `$('#table-user-results').DataTable(true, {` with responsive.recalc. otherwise the headers would still show 2 but the rows would show 3 columns but the 3rd transparent, being able to see the column was there but empty.

Comment: @Tsukasa, that seems wrong. Also I forgot to mention since you're using the scroller you also need to call `scroller.measure()` as mentioned in the article;

Comment: @Tsukasa, `DataTable()` only accepts object as a parameter, AFAIK.

Comment: I didn't think so. I added an image of what it was doing until I threw that true in there. I get no errors in the console either from adding `true` either.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120187/discussion-between-tsukasa-and-gyrocode-com).

Comment: @Tsukasa, I found an issue with jQuery DataTables based on your case, you need to use `scrollCollapse: true`. Please see an example in the answer for demonstration.

Comment: Finally [fixed in Responsive](https://github.com/DataTables/Scroller/issues/66)! It will be in the next release/